Help with proof of Ray-Knight theorem
I'm trying to understand the paper "A direct proof of the Ray-Knight theorem" by McGill, and am stuck on one lemma. Here is a screenshot of the part I'm stuck on:


I understand up until the last equation. However, if at that point we let $\epsilon \to 0$ then I think $m_\epsilon^1  \to m_0$ and $u(\epsilon) \to 1$, then if we let $\alpha \to 0$, then I think $exp(-\alpha m_0) \to 1$ on $\{m_0 < \infty\}$, and $exp(-\alpha m_0) \to 0$ on $\{m_0 = \infty\}$. Then let $c \to 0$, it seems to me that we get
$$
P(m_0 < \infty) = E[u(Z_1)].
$$
My problem is that it says earlier that $u$ is decreasing, and $u(0) = 1$. So, then, isn't $E[u(Z_1)] < 1$? But then $P(m_0 < \infty) < 1$, which is the opposite of what is claimed. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks,
Greg

Bear in mind that $u=u_\alpha$ depends on $\alpha$. In view of the formula for $u_\alpha$ in terms of the modified Bessel function, you have $\lim_{\alpha\to 0}u_\alpha(z) =1$. So, having let $\epsilon\to 0$, you have
$$
E[\exp(-\alpha m^1_0); c<Z_1]=e^{-\alpha}E[u_\alpha(Z_1); c<Z_1].
$$
Now let $\alpha\to 0$ to get
$$
P[m^1_0<\infty; c<Z_1]=P[c<Z_1].
$$
Finally let $c\to 0$. The calculation of $\lim_{\alpha\to 0}E[u_\alpha(Z_1); c<Z_1]$ will need some estimate based on $K_1$ to allow use of the dominated convergence theorem. I'll leave that to you.
It is known that $K_1(x)\sim 1/x$ as $x\to 0$, but that's not quite enough I think.

Ah, that's it! Yes, I can see I was missing that $u$ has dependence on $\alpha$, and so basically in my argument $E[u(Z_1)]$ does equal 1, modulo the technical details you mention. Many thanks!
